# Can't find Excel VBA formula type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am getting type mismatch 13 error and I can't see where it is.

Here is the code.

```
Set concRange = Range(Cells(11, 48), Cells((10 + noDilutions), 48))
Set deadRange = Range(Cells(11, 49), Cells((10 + noDilutions), 49))
analysisSheet.Cells(f, 14).Value = _
    (WorksheetFunction.Lookup(WorksheetFunction.Index(deadRange, _
    WorksheetFunction.CountIf(deadRange, " >= " & _
    (WorksheetFunction.Max(deadRange) / 2))), deadRange, concRange)) _
    - (((WorksheetFunction.Index(deadRange, WorksheetFunction.CountIf _
    (deadRange, " >= " & (WorksheetFunction.Max(deadRange) / 2)))) _
    - (WorksheetFunction.Max(deadRange) / 2)) * ((WorksheetFunction.Lookup _
    (WorksheetFunction.Index(deadRange, WorksheetFunction.CountIf(deadRange, _
    " >= " & (WorksheetFunction.Max(deadRange) / 2))), deadRange, concRange)) _
    - (WorksheetFunction.Lookup(WorksheetFunction.Index(deadRange, _
    WorksheetFunction.CountIf(deadRange, " <= " & _
    (WorksheetFunction.Max(deadRange) / 2))), deadRange, concRange))) _
    / ((WorksheetFunction.Index(deadRange, WorksheetFunction.CountIf(deadRange, _
    " >= " & (WorksheetFunction.Max(deadRange) / 2)))) _
    - (WorksheetFunction.Index(deadRange, WorksheetFunction.CountIf _
    (deadRange, " <= " & (WorksheetFunction.Max(deadRange) / 2))))))
```

I've tried changing "WorksheetFunction" to "Application" and "Application.WorksheetFunction".

Yes it is a very very long formula :D

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: that is a very large formula! The way I would approach this is to break it up into pieces and make sure each piece works. You will quickly find the error source. For easier to read code, you could also set each calculation to a variable and then do them one at a time, then place your final answer variable as the `cell.value`

Comment: I might be off, not really understanding the formula, but I wonder if the string derived for the Countif needs a final " for example "<=40"  rather than "<"&40

Comment: There's a lot of stuff missing here if we are to help you with this.  But #1 on the list is that we sure cannot help you with a Type Mismatch if you do not include all of your declarations.

Comment: A prime example of VBA spaghetti code. Like the other comments, if there is logic here, you can split it in steps and follow bit by bit. I see a lot of the same `.Index(deadReange,..)` which hints at where to start with splitting the code.

Comment: [beautifying it](http://pastebin.com/8SB7p1Qg) doesn't even help me understand what it is doing. This is a prime example of something that should be calculated in stages for **readability** and **maintenance**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, writting a formula like that is a really bad idea, for three main reasons:

- It's virtually impossible to understand
- It's virtually impossible to debug
- It it repeats many calculations = inefficient

Refactoring, it becomes

```
With WorksheetFunction
    A = .Max(deadRange)
    B = .CountIf(deadRange, " >= " & (A / 2))
    C = .CountIf(deadRange, " <= " & (A / 2))
    D = .Index(deadRange, B)
    E = .Index(deadRange, C)
    F = .Lookup(D, deadRange, concRange)
    G = .Lookup(E, deadRange, concRange)

    analysisSheet.Cells(ff, 14).Value = _
        F - ((D - (A / 2)) * (F - G) / (D - E))
End With
```

Debugging this reveals the problem: the `spaces` around `>=` in `.CountIf(deadRange, " >= " & (A / 2))` is the cause of the error.

So, use instead

```
    B = .CountIf(deadRange, ">=" & (A / 2))
    C = .CountIf(deadRange, "<=" & (A / 2))
```

Comment: +1 For effort. Your three reasons listed are so true that I'm not even sure if this answer is correct. And I'm happy not checking. It _looks_ good. Great job on the refactoring!

Comment: +1. It looks like you untangled a necklace that had been sitting in the bottom of a drawer.

Comment: Incredible thank you. Sorry for not reading it sooner I was occupied with something else for few days :D

Comment: There should be a badge 'Formatting Ninja' for what you've done!